# GitLink: Retrieve list of files which were changed in a commit

Tags: packages, gitlink

How can I retrieve the list of files that were changed in a commit using [GitLink](https://github.com/WolframResearch/GitLink/)?

I can open a repo like this:

```
repo = GitOpen["~/Repos/GitLink"]
```

Now I can get the list of commits:

```
commits = GitRange[repo, "HEAD"];
```

I can examine the state of the repository at a certain commit using `GitExpandTree`:

```
GitExpandTree[commits[[1]]]
```

[image]

In principle, I could take two commits, expand all subtrees, then check which blobs have a differing `"SHA"` property.  This sounds complicated and I am sure there is a simple, direct way. Unfortunately, I cannot find it.

---

Note: I know that this could be done by running the external `git` executable, but I would like to know if it can be done using GitLink directly.

Answer (score 5):

`` GitLink`Private`gitDiffTrees `` seems to do the job:

```
GitLink`Private`gitDiffTrees[
  ToGitObject[repo, "HEAD"]["Tree"],
  ToGitObject[repo, "HEAD^1"]["Tree"]
]
```

> { list of files }